# Adding action button (icon) on top right corner of the shiny dashboard box

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would require an action button icon on the top right corner of the shiny dashboard box. The below code appends the icons 'refresh' and 'plus' adjacent to the 'Title1'. However, I would require the icons to be placed at the right side end of the header bar (Similar to the positions of minimize, restore and close button in windows application).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    box(
      title = p("Title 1", 
                actionButton("titleBtId", "", icon = icon("refresh"),
                             class = "btn-xs", title = "Update"),
                actionButton('titleBtid2', '', icon = icon('plus'),
                             class='btn-xs', title = 'update')
      ), 
      width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "warning",
      uiOutput("boxContentUI2")
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Row layout"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  body
)

server = function(input, output, session) { 
  
  output$boxContentUI2 <- renderUI({
    input$titleBtId
    pre(paste(sample(LETTERS,10), collapse = ", "))
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a style declaration with absolute positioning to your action buttons.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    box(
      title = p("Title 1", 
                actionButton("titleBtId", "", icon = icon("refresh"),
                             class = "btn-xs", title = "Update", style = "position: absolute; right: 40px"),
                actionButton('titleBtid2', '', icon = icon('plus'),
                             class = 'btn-xs', title = 'update', style = "position: absolute; right: 10px")
      ), 
      width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "warning",
      uiOutput("boxContentUI2")
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Row layout"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  body
)

server = function(input, output, session) { 
  
  output$boxContentUI2 <- renderUI({
    input$titleBtId
    pre(paste(sample(LETTERS,10), collapse = ", "))
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]